# Git ignore the deletion of a tracked file

Tags: git, gitignore

## scenario

I've a folder `/build` that is regenerated at each build process. This folder needs to be versioned and the content must be excluded, so in the `.gitignore` I've added `build/*` and a `/build/.gitkeep` to be able to add the folder.

## problem

When the content is generated it deletes the `.gitkeep` file that was previously tracked by git. I would like to know if there is any way to ignore the deletion of this file. I'm looking  for a solution that can works across repos, since `git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` only seems to work locally and would need to be executed on each clone.

Comment: Why do you need to track an empty folder?

Comment: @golergka the folder is a dependency of other tool, if it's not there it will fail on startup when configuring the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assume-unchanged command can be run automatically on each client if you add it in a [post-checkout hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L149) in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like something you could achieve with your build tool.
What are you using to build? could you look into making a script that writes the `.gitkeep` file to the `build/` folder after a build operation has been executed?

The script would be very simple, along the lines of (in a unix system):

```
#!/bin/sh
touch build/.gitkeep
```